# Null Pointers in my Queue (Link Lists)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list, queue

Okay, I have this program almost done, but I'm lost at this point. I'm returning null pointers (it says on line 44 but that's just a while loop) and I need help fixing it please. I use a linked list to implement my queue, and my other two classes pass 100%, so the final class (CarQueue) is where the problem lies that is creating a Null Pointer.

```
    public class CarQueue<E> {

    private LinkNode<E> head;
    private LinkNode<E> tail;

    public CarQueue() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public CarQueue(E newData) {
        LinkNode<E> temp = new LinkNode<E>(newData, null);
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }

    public void addToQueue(E newData) {
        LinkNode<E> temp = new LinkNode<E>(newData, null);
        if (empty() == false) {
            tail.setNext(temp);
            tail = temp;
        } else {
            head = temp;
            tail.setNext(temp);
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        LinkNode<E> temp = head;
        String cars = "";
        while (temp.getNext() != null) {
            cars += temp.toString() + '\n';
        }
        return cars;
    }

    public E removeFmQueue() {
        LinkNode<E> headReturn = head;
        head = head.getNext();
        return headReturn.getData();

    }

    public LinkNode<E> peek() {
        return head.getNext();
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        if (head == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Going strictly off my spec, I was told to set up an empty constructor, in which head is null, yes, but in my second constructor head should be the value of temp node. The 2nd constructor is setup as if there is one element in the queue, thus head and tail are both temp. According to my test, while (temp.getNext() != null) is throwing the exception, getNext is fine, it was setup in my LinkNode class that works perfectly and passes all tests. I'm not sure why I'm getting the null exactly. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If

```
while (temp.getNext() != null)  {
```

is the line throwing an exception, then `temp` is null, (or, if it's even possible, `getNext()` is throwing a `NullPointerException`). But let's assume `temp` is the problem.

`temp` is being assigned to `head`, so is `head` being assigned to `null`?

If the zero-parameter constructor is called, but no other functions are called before calling `toString()`, then this would indeed result in `temp` being assigned `null`. Therefore, when you attempt `temp.getNext()`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

To prevent this, you could have an alternative value returned by the `toString()` method:

```
public String toString()  {
   if(head == null)  {
      return  "no head. I got nothing.";
   }

   //print the other stuff...
}
```

But, really, the best solution is to never allow head--and therefore temp--to be null, as this means your class is in an unstable and basically-unusable state.

The most obvious way to prevent this is to eliminate the zero-parameter constructor--or alternatively have it *only* call the other constructor with a non-null value--and ensure that the other constructor *never* lets head remain as null.

Comment: I need to follow the latter solution, but I don't know what is making my head null or what my head should be instead

Comment: I can't remove that constructor though. My instructor had me set it up that way when I was working with him, so it's a part of my assignment.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate the help. I'll fiddle around with it a bit, but I think the problem lies in my temp, now that I took a long look at my code.
LinkNode<E> temp = new LinkNode<E>(newData, null);
I think this line is my issue. my first NPX occurs in a condition that is only supposed to be used if the queue is empty (in the addToQueue method), so I'm assigning my head and tail values to temp, so temp must be empty, but the only point I'm setting temp I'm setting it to (newData, null). I'm not sure what that null does exactly, but that may be my issue with the NPXs everywhere

Comment: I can't upvote, not enough "reputation points" or something. Believe me, I tried haha